# Why is this global counter variable not working with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, animation, global-variables, settimeout, counter

I am trying to animate some text by alternating the color of every other char. My code is working as far as styling it one way, but `setTimeout` is not calling it again to alternate the text color.

The problem seems to be my use of a global variable as a counter, which may be a simple problem that I am overlooking.

Any ideas? Here is my javascript code:

```
var num = 0;
function animateText(){
    var str = "";
    var title = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;

    for(var i = 0; i < title.length; i++){
        if(num % 2 == 0){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                str += '<span style = "color: silver;">' + title.charAt(i) + '</span>';
            } else {
                str += title.charAt(i) + "";
            }
        } else {
            if(i % 2 != 0) {
                str += '<span style = "color: silver;">' + title.charAt(i) + '</span>';
            } else {
                str += title.charAt(i) = "";
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = str;
    num++;

    if(num == 10) 
        num = 0;

    setTimeout("animateText()", 500);

}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks guys -- fixing the typo and passing setTimeout a function reference is working. However, the animation is crashing the browser -- it seems as if the first line (`var str = "";`) is not evaluating after the first iteration... Instead the output is resembling the += operation. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the typo that Jonathan points out, your logic seems flawed.  The first time through the function, you get the initial string and build some HTML with various `<span>` tags in it.  The next time through the function, you get the innerHTML from the DOM element and start processing it again as if it was just your string, but this time it's the previous HTML with all the tags in it - it's not the string you started with.  You will need to save the original string somewhere unmodified so you can start with just the text string each time through the function rather than build on the previous formatted HTML each time.

Comment: Great, thanks for that -- that is an easy solution, and now it works. Also thanks to @JonathanLonowski for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error / typo:

```
str += title.charAt(i) = "";
//                     ^
```

This is an illegal assignment, as a JavaScript console would've told you:

> ```
> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
> ```

But, you can also pass `setTimeout` a function reference rather than a string:

```
setTimeout(animateText, 500);
```

This will skip the internal `eval` and will allow the timeout to use functions defined in scopes other than "global."

Answer (score 0):

Global variable is just fine

There is a syntax in your code at this line

```
str += title.charAt(i) = "";
```

This is not a valid assignment